# Haskell - List comprehension in a list of tuples (a,[a])

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

So, let's go to the point:

```
f :: Eq a => a -> [(a,[a])] -> [(a,[a])]
f x list = [(a,[m]) | (a,[m]) <- list, x == a]
```

so:

```
   f 1 [(1,[1])] = [(1,[1])]
```

but

```
  f 1 [(1,[1,1])] = []
```

Why is that??
Thank you!

(I'm a newbie, so I apologize if it's a too dumb question, but I really can't find an explanation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `[1,1]` does not match the pattern `[m]`. The latter means a list of one item (unless used where a type name should be). Haskell already knows that second element of the pair is a list, (by looking at the type of `list` parameter) and does not need to be told that explicitly.

Comment: I just had a mind-blowing moment now! haha. Exactly, the [m] means a list of one element, now I get it. Thank you very much! =D